# MySQL - Update column values using subquery select itself

Tags: mysql

Please help me with MySQL update to update the column with result returns from select itself.

For instance, I have two tables

> TABLE user(
>     userid int,
>     groupid int
>   )
>
> TABLE thread (
>     threadid int,
>     userid int,
>     sticky tinyint,
>     vip tinyint
>   )

Now I'm trying to achieve this with a single update query, but can't seem to do it. What I thought I should do is:

```
UPDATE user SET groupid=15 WHERE userid IN (SELECT userid FROM thread t LEFT JOIN user u ON u.userid=t.userid WHERE (t.sticky=1 AND t.vip=1) AND (u.groupid=11 OR u.groupid=14) GROUP BY t.userid);
```

but MySQL saids: **#1093 - You can't specify target table 'user' for update in FROM clause**

Please help me!

Comment: Generally, in the absence of any aggregating functions, a GROUP BY clause is a bad idea. MySQL forgives (and even optimizes) the aberration, but it often leads to unexpected or erroneous results. Also, unless you include an IS NULL comparison, an LEFT JOIN on a table from which you select no columns is just plain weird!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysql error 1093 - Can't specify target table for update in FROM clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause)

Comment: GROUP BY because of the result returns duplicate userid. 

How can I solve the problem, with single query only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done by generating a new table from left join of two tables and then update from the filtered result, syntax will be as follows:

```
UPDATE user AS nu 
 INNER JOIN
  (SELECT u.userid, u.groupid 
  FROM thread t LEFT JOIN user u 
      ON u.userid=t.userid 
  WHERE (t.sticky=1 AND t.vip=1) AND 
       (u.groupid=11 OR u.groupid=14) 
  GROUP BY t.userid) AS my_table
 ON nu.userid = my_table.userid 
SET nu.groupid = 15;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But the error returns: #1288 - The target table my_table of the UPDATE is not updatable

Comment: @hatxi: now it should work, in earlier case a new table my_table was formed which is just a temporary table from outcome of left join.

Comment: Thank you Rockse, it returns error: #1052 - Column 'userid' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: it's still error: #1054 - Unknown column 'u.userid' in 'on clause'

Comment: please add a sqlfiddle, it some silly syntax error which could be solved easily.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following:

```
UPDATE user u2 SET u2.groupid=15 WHERE u2.userid IN (SELECT userid FROM thread t LEFT JOIN user u ON u.userid=t.userid WHERE (t.sticky=1 AND t.vip=1) AND (u.groupid=11 OR u.groupid=14) GROUP BY t.userid);
```

This should do the trick, hope it helps :)

Comment: #1093 - You can't specify target table 'u2' for update in FROM clause :(

Comment: sorry to hear that, I'll do some research and change my answer

Answer (score 0):

Is your desired query materially different from this...

```
UPDATE user u
  JOIN thread t 
    ON t.userid = u.userid 
   SET groupid = 15
 WHERE t.sticky = 1 
   AND t.vip = 1
   AND u.groupid IN(11,14);
```

?

If so, then as Rockse suggests, consider providin proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem, together with a corresponding desired result set.

Answer (score 0):

```
update user1 u
left join thread1 t on t.userid = u.userid
where (t.sticky=1 AND t.vip=1) AND (u.groupid=11 OR u.groupid=14) 
set u.groupid = 15
GROUP BY t.userid;

Use this
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add this before your query:

```
use yourdatabase;
```

yourdatabase is database name which includes user table